# Sum values of column in time window defined start/stop event

Tags: sql, datetime, aggregate-functions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, gaps-and-islands

I'm struggling to write SQL window function in Snowflake to sum consecutive values within column.

Data in `stg_events` table:

| robot_id | timestamp | msg_type | obj_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-12-14 09:30:00.000 | route_start | NULL |
| 1 | 2020-12-14 09:30:00.100 | object_detected | 2 |
| 1 | 2020-12-14 09:30:00.300 | object_detected | 1 |
| 1 | 2020-12-14 09:30:05.000 | object_detected | 2 |
| 1 | 2020-12-14 09:30:40.000 | route_stop | NULL |

Desired output of SQL statement, I'm trying to write:

| robot_id | route_id | route_start | route_stop | sum_obj |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2020-12-14 09:30:00.000 | 2020-12-14 09:30:40.000 | 5 |

I provided just example of one route for one robot but there will be more robots pushing data into the table and also more routes.

Thanks a lot for any ideas!

Comment: does each robot use exactly one route

Comment: Route is one run of the robot. Robot can be doing one route at a time.

Comment: @JKC . . . You might want to ask a new question with more realistic data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the same robot may have several routes, aggregation alone cannot solve the problem. This is a gaps-and-island problem, where an island starts with a "route_start" message type and ends with "route_stop".

If the starts and stops properly interleave, here is an approach using window functions:

```
select robot_id, min(timestamp) as route_start, max(timestamp) as route_end, sum(obj_count) as obj_count
from (
    select t.*,
        sum(case when msg_type = 'route_start' then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by robot_id order by timestamp) as cnt_start,
        sum(case when msg_type = 'route_stop'  then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by robot_id order by timestamp rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) as cnt_end
    from mytable t
) t
where cnt_start = coalesce(cnt_end, 0) + 1
group by robot_id, cnt_start
```

The idea is to count the starts (up to the current row included) and stops (up to the preceding row) and to compare the two values to identify the islands. The rest is just aggregation.

Here is **[a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b6642c70e467c6b4c8aa863122e583d9)**, with less contrived sample data:

```
robot_id | timestamp             | msg_type        | obj_count
-------: | :-------------------- | :-------------- | --------:
       1 | 2020-12-14 09:30:00   | route_start     |      null
       1 | 2020-12-14 09:30:00.1 | object_detected |         2
       1 | 2020-12-14 09:30:00.3 | object_detected |         1
       1 | 2020-12-14 09:30:05   | object_detected |         2
       1 | 2020-12-14 09:30:40   | route_stop      |      null
       1 | 2020-12-15 00:30:00   | route_start     |      null
       1 | 2020-12-15 00:30:05   | object_detected |         2
       1 | 2020-12-15 00:30:40   | route_stop      |      null
```

Results:

```
robot_id | route_start         | route_end           | obj_count
-------: | :------------------ | :------------------ | --------:
       1 | 2020-12-14 09:30:00 | 2020-12-14 09:30:40 |         5
       1 | 2020-12-15 00:30:00 | 2020-12-15 00:30:40 |         2
```

Comment: why all this , the answer below is the easiest way.

Comment: @ETL_Devs: why is explained at the beginning of the answer. If a robot has several routes, simple aggregation fails. Note that there is no `route_id` in OP's data - you may want to try the aggregation query in the fiddle I provided, that has more data.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Just one more thing. I tested your SQL in scenario where I actually have 2 robots and they overlap. In fact it means that both robots are working at the same time. In that case, the SQL you provided returns `obj_count` only for the events related to the last route, for the rest it returns `NULL`. Do you see any way how to adjust the SQL to support multiple robots with overlapping routes? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JKC: the query handles multiple robots already. I added the scenario you mentionned to the fiddle, it appears to work: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e0fda78d87e4aabf6d5da7909d976c44

Comment: Might be something Snowflake specific. I will figure it out. Thanks a lot again for your help and great end to end example. Terrific job!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP BY` and aggregation function as follows:

```
select robot_id, 
       route_id,
       min(timestamp) as route_start,
       max(timestamp) as route_end,
       sum(obj_count) as obj_count
  from stg_events t
group by robot_id, route_id
```

Comment: you have to consider null in obj_count

Comment: sum ignores null

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple starts for a robot, you want to assign a grouping to each group -- which you call `route_id`.  The simplest method is a cumulative sum of "starts".  Then aggregate:

```
select robot_id, route_id,
       min(timestamp) as route_start,
       max(timestamp) as route_end,
       sum(obj_count) as obj_count
from (select e.*,
             sum(case when msg_type = 'route_start' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by robot_id order by timestamp) as route_id
      from stg_events e
group by robot_id, route_id;
```

Note:  This does not consider `'route_end'`.  It is unclear what you want when that is not the last row before the next start.